# Mouse focus on Popup window

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, aero

I have a very anoying issue with my Win7. I have a `Dell Latitude E6430`, I recently installed win7 and I didn't have the Aero theme because my Intel Graphic driver was obsolete. I searched in the web and found an `exe` file, I succeeded to get Aero working well.

The only issue I am facing : **pop-up windows can't get mouse focus.**

For instance, when I click on the arrow in the task bar to show hidden icons in the notification area, I can see the pop-up window with icons, but I can't do anything with it, It disapears always after I move the mouse.

Can you explain me please what is the cause of that ??

[image]

**Edit**

Another example is when I right click on the icon of an opened application :

[image]

It's very anoying !!!

Comment: Which driver version are you currently using? Where did you get the driver setup executable?

Comment: Do you mean you can't get mouse focus on **any** popup windows, or is it just that specific pop-up window in the taskbar? You could of course tell the taskbar to always display all notification icons, which would solve the problem by not needing to get a popup at all; but if you are seeing other examples of popup windows disappear, let us know some other examples.

Comment: @allquixotic, I can get focus on any popup windows ! see my edit for the other example

Comment: @and31415 I got the setup exe from google searches, I think from [softpedia website](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BLUETOOTH/Dell/) ! Currently my driver version is : **8.15.10.2639**

Comment: @mansoulx The driver you downloaded might be a generic or otherwise incompatible version. Your laptop model supports Windows 7, so you should uninstall the current driver, restart Windows and then download and install latest driver available on the [Dell support page](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/Product/latitude-e6430). When you're done, restart Windows. Then make sure the Aero interface is enabled, and check whether you get the same issue.

Comment: @and31415, I did exactly what you told me. I uninstalled the driver, restarted windows, and windows automatically install a `Standard Driver for Intel Graphics`, but even with this, the problem is still here. I'm asking myself if it's due to the driver or not ?! I am really lost ...

Comment: @mansoulx What's the driver version right now? In case you haven't already, try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) and see whether you get the same issue.

Comment: The version is `6.1.7600.16385` ! Let me try the clean boot and get back to you ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

This works (for me)!

1. Open Start then Run and type “regedit” (without quotes). If Run isn't there, type regedit in the search bar.
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
3. Right-click on the empty space and create a new DWORD value named ForegroundLockTimeout, or modify the existing value named ‘ForegroundLockTimeout’, set or modify the value to 0. (This value will cause the application to take the focus instantly.)
4. That’s it. Exit regedit and restart Windows 7 for changes to come into effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it unfortunately doesn't work !!! I modified the existing value to 0, restarted the computer ...

Comment: The problem with the answer is it gives malicious people ideas for how to CAUSE this problem!

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like your mouse issues a click when it moves. Have you tried connecting anothother mouse to your system to test if it happens here as well?

Reinstalling the drivers may fix the issue, but it may also be a hardware problem.

Comment: Yes I tried with other mouses ! I reinstalled also all mouse drivers, but still getting the issue. I think I am going to reinstall all the win 7 system, I have tried many things without any effect :) !

Answer (score -1):

I've suffering the same thing *sometimes*. 
Just tried the register tweak "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" 'ForegroundLockTimeout". 
It had the value 30d40 Hexadecimal (200000 Decimal) 
and changed it to 0. 
After restart it worked for a few seconds/minutes. 
I found a work-around by **right-clicking and drag-up** to the icon-window

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtEgV.png

and click the desired icon.